# Why i can't send the information of equipped tool from Local Script to Server Script?

Tags: lua, roblox

Im Trying to invoke Remote Function to send tool information when i equip the tool. On breakpoints, tool enters to variable but on server side, player's information sended always

local script on weapon:

```
tool.Equipped:Connect(function()

    local weaponType = tool

    GetWeaponInformation:InvokeServer(weaponType)
    BindFireInput:Invoke()

end)
```

ServerScript:

```
function getWeaponInformation(weaponInformation)
    print(weaponInformation)
    return  weaponInformation

end

GetWeaponInformation.OnServerInvoke = getWeaponInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getWeaponInformation(player, weaponInformation) --changes made here
    print(weaponInformation)
    return  weaponInformation
end

GetWeaponInformation.OnServerInvoke = getWeaponInformation
```

The first argument is always the player.